# matching two columns of different data table with string partially

Tags: r, merge

I have two big data tables,
df1 with one column (full.name)

```
full.name  
brad pitt
shah rukh khan       
salman khan
taylor swift
justin bieber
xyz abc
```

and df2 with two column name and age

```
name         age
brad         10
shah         15
salman khan  20
taylor       30
justin       25
```

and my desired output is

```
full.name            name          age
brad pitt            brad          10
shah rukh khan       shah          15
salman khan          salman khan   20
taylor swift         taylor        30
justin bieber        justin        25
```

but I wanted to match column by string only 
till nowI was using `inner_join()` but it was working for those values which were matching exactly so i want to match by string

Comment: Your example makes the (not realistic) assumption that you will not have say two people with the name 'Brad'. Are 'Brad Pitt' and 'Brad Anderson' essentialy the same? Do both go under the name 'Brad'?

Comment: By data table, do you mean `data.table`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**sample data**

```
library( data.table )

dt1 <- fread("full.name
brad pitt
             shah rukh khan       
             salman khan
             taylor swift
             justin bieber
             xyz abc", sep = "%")

dt2 <- fread('name,         age
brad,         10
shah,         15
salman khan,  20
taylor,       30
justin,       25')
```

**code**

```
library( fuzzyjoin )
regex_left_join( dt1, dt2, by = c( full.name = "name" ) )
```

**output**

```
#         full.name        name age
# 1:      brad pitt        brad  10
# 2: shah rukh khan        shah  15
# 3:    salman khan salman khan  20
# 4:   taylor swift      taylor  30
# 5:  justin bieber      justin  25
# 6:        xyz abc        <NA>  NA
```

Comment: hi, how can I match two columns with string exactly. I want to match strings if they exactly match with others. and I also want data of first df which doesn't match. can you help me with this

Comment: @xyz that sounds like a straight forward left join... you can find plenty of examples of those when searching SO.

Answer (score 0):

For a solution using `data.table` only you can try:

```
df2[, full := lapply(name, function(x) grep(x, df1[, full.name], value = TRUE) )]
```

And to get an inner join you can add:

```
df2[lapply(full, length)>0, ]
```